# Delete Button to Delete a User Record PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, delete-record

The below code is all on one file named 'useraccount.php' on my website. As it currently exists, this page has a form for the logged in administrator to add a new user account, as well as a table below that displays existing accounts already in the database. I am wanting to add a 'delete' button for each existing account, and have tried various ways of incorporating this, but have yet to find a solution that works. If anyone can share some expertise with me I would greatly appreciate it. I need to know how to setup the button to carry over the database row number variable so that the php can recognize which row to delete, as well as where and how to safely execute the delete query in the php. Notes are within the code that show my partial attempt.

## Current PHP Code

```
<?php 

require("connect.php");

if(empty($_SESSION['user']) || empty($_SESSION['adminaccess']))
{ 
    header("Location: login.php"); 
    die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
}

//BEGIN DATA FETCHING TO DISPLAY CURRENT USERS
$query = " 
    SELECT 
        id, 
        username,
        display_name, 
        email,
        admin
    FROM users 
"; 

try 
{ 
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{ 
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
//END DATA FETCHING TO DISPLAY CURRENT USERS



//BEGIN USER DELETE FUNCTION
//IM NOT SURE HOW TO SET THIS UP, OR IF IT'S EVEN IN THE RIGHT PLACE

$id = isset($_POST['id'])?intval($_POST['id']):0;
if($id>0) { $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '$id'";
}
//END USER DELETE FUNCTION



//BEGIN FOR ADD NEW USER
if(!empty($_POST)) 
{ 
    if(empty($_POST['username'])) 
    { 
        header("Location: useraccounts.php");
        die("Redirecting to: useraccounts.php");
        $error = "Please enter a username.";
    } 

    if(empty($_POST['password'])) 
    { 
        header("Location: useraccounts.php");
        die("Redirecting to: useraccounts.php");
        $error = "Please enter a password."; 
    } 

    if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    { 
        header("Location: useraccounts.php");
        die("Redirecting to: useraccounts.php");
        $error = "Invalid E-Mail Address"; 
    } 

    $query = "
        SELECT 
            1 
        FROM users 
        WHERE 
            username = :username 
    "; 

    $query_params = array( 
        ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
    ); 

    try 
    { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

    if($row) 
    { 
        header("Location: useraccounts.php");
        die("Redirecting to: useraccounts.php");
        $error = "This username is already in use"; 
    } 

    $query = " 
        SELECT 
            1 
        FROM users 
        WHERE 
            email = :email 
    "; 

    $query_params = array( 
        ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
    ); 

    try 
    { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

    if($row) 
    { 
        header("Location: useraccounts.php");
        die("Redirecting to: useraccounts.php");
        $error = "This email address is already registered"; 
    } 

    $query = " 
        INSERT INTO users ( 
            username,
            display_name,
            password,
            salt,
            email,
            admin
        ) VALUES ( 
            :username,
            :display_name,
            :password,
            :salt,
            :email,
            :admin
        ) 
    "; 

    $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 

    $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 

    for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
    { 
        $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); 
    } 

    $query_params = array( 
        ':username' => $_POST['username'],
        ':display_name' => $_POST['display_name'],
        ':password' => $password,
        ':salt' => $salt, 
        ':email' => $_POST['email'],
        ':admin' => $_POST['admin'] 
    ); 

    try 
    { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    header("Location: useraccounts.php"); 
    die("Redirecting to useraccounts.php"); 
}
?>
```

## Table that Displays 'Add New Account' Form

```
<h3>Add an Account</h3>
<form action="useraccounts.php" method="post"> 
<p class="label">Username:</p> 
    <input class="text" type="text" name="username" value="" />
<p class="label">Display Name(s):</p> 
    <input class="text" type="text" name="display_name" value="" />
<p class="label">E-Mail:</p> 
    <input class="text" type="text" name="email" value="" />
<p class="label">Password:</p> 
    <input class="text" type="password" name="password" value="" />
<p class="label">Admin Account?</p> 
    <input type="radio" id="r1" name="admin" value="0" checked="checked" /><label for="r1"><span></span>No</label>
    <input type="radio" id="r2" name="admin" value="1" /><label for="r2"><span></span>Yes</label></br>
<p class="error"><?php echo $error; ?></p>
<button class="contact" type="submit" name="submit">Create Account</button> 
</form>
```

## Table that Displays Existing User Account

```
<h3>Current Accounts List</h3>
<table class="parent-accounts"> 
<tr>
    <th><h4>ID</h4></th> 
    <th><h4>Username</h4></th> 
    <th><h4>Display Name(s)</h4></th>
    <th><h4>E-Mail Address</h4></th>
    <th><h4>Admin</h4></th>
</tr>
<?php foreach($rows as $row): ?> 
<form action="useraccounts.php?id=<?php echo $id['id'];?>" method="post">
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['display_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['admin'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete User" /></td>
</tr>
</form>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: in Displays Existing User Account, inside form, couple of things with `$id` you have it in form action, also 2 hidden inputs at end with `name="id"` so either use input (only 1) and remove `?id=<?php echo $id['id'];?>` or keep `?id=<?php echo $id['id'];?>` and remove both inputs with `name="id"`

Comment: Thanks for you time! I have removed the two hidden fields with `name="id"` and left the `?id=<?php echo $id['id'];?>` in the form action. However, it still doesn't seem to remove a record from the database. Can you review the section in the php where I have noted `//BEGIN USER DELETE FUNCTION` to see what I might be leaving out there. I'm not sure what else it could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'id' is posted by the form, and your Delete User Query seems fine. You need to execute the query. And maybe make sure you handle the deleting request before you fetching current users.

```js
<?php 

require("connect.php");

if(empty($_SESSION['user']) || empty($_SESSION['adminaccess']))
{ 
    header("Location: login.php"); 
    die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
}

//BEGIN USER DELETE FUNCTION
//IM NOT SURE HOW TO SET THIS UP, OR IF IT'S EVEN IN THE RIGHT PLACE
if(isset($_SESSION['adminaccess']))  //if user has admin privilege
{
    $id = isset($_POST['id'])?intval($_POST['id']):0;
    if($id>0)  //if valid id for deleting is posted
    { 
      $query = 'DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '.$id;
      echo '<script>alert("Query: '.$query.'");</script>';  //debug line, remove this later
      try
      {
         $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
         $stmt->execute();
      }
      catch(PDOException $ex)
      {
         die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
      }
    }
    else
    {
       echo '<script>alert("Invalid ID: '.$id.'");</script>';  //debug line, remove this later
    }
}
else
{
    echo '<script>alert("No admin access privilege.");</script>';  //debug line, remove this later
}
//END USER DELETE FUNCTION

//BEGIN DATA FETCHING TO DISPLAY CURRENT USERS
$query = " 
    SELECT 
        id, 
        username,
        display_name, 
        email,
        admin
    FROM users 
"; 

try 
{ 
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{ 
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
//END DATA FETCHING TO DISPLAY CURRENT USERS

..........


?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried this out and when I click the 'Delete User' button, for some reason it still doesn't delete it from the database. It pretty much just goes back to the page without executing the delete query.

Comment: In that case, try put some debug lines: if(isset($_SESSION['adminaccess']))  //if user has admin priviledge
{
    $id = isset($_POST['id'])?intval($_POST['id']):0;
    echo '<script>alert("Id to Delete: "'.$id.'")</script>'
    if($id>0)  //if valid id for deleting is posted
    { 
      $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '".$id."'";
      echo '<script>alert("q:"'.$query.'")</script>'
      try
      {
         $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
         $stmt->execute();
      }
      catch(PDOException $ex)
      {
         die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
      }
    }
}

Comment: Sorry, It is a bit hard to format code in comments. Try add some debug lines (such as echo '<script>alert("some info")</script>' or echo'<script>console.log("some info")'</script> and see what message you get. 
Then you can tell which part of PHP code has been executed.

Comment: Here is what I get when I go to the page now… Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/amyshous/public_html/admin/useraccounts.php on line 29

Comment: Line 29 is the first line with the echo

Comment: Just edited the previous code snippet to make it easier to see. Please let me know which line is causing the syntax error? is the first alert for showing the id? or is the second alert for showing the query?

Comment: you have 2 line breaks here `echo '<script>alert("Query: '.$query.'");</script>';` cause the syntax error.

Comment: Okay, when I click delete for the record with id=45, I got a prompt said "Id to delete: 0" and when I click ok, i get the following warning… Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at path…/useraccounts.php:27) in path…/useraccounts.php on line 90
Redirecting to: useraccounts.php

Comment: @Shebary First one is for Javascript and the second one is for Php echo line. It should not cause syntax error. Although, you can omit the first ; if you want to.

Comment: @AaronMyers Ok, you got the Id to delete, that means Id is posted successfully. Now remove the first echo line and see if you can see the query string as an alert.

Comment: @PeterPeng, just helping, the answer and effort will be yours and my upvote if it gets resolved, just to be clear, 2 line breaks, so should be like `echo '<script>alert("Query: '.$query.'")'; echo'</script>';`

Comment: @Peter I've removed the first echo line only, and this time I get no prompt. The record does not delete. It has the same behavior as before where I click delete, and it refreshes the page without deleting the record.

Comment: It also might be worth noting that in the form action, I had to change $id in `<?php echo $id['id'];?>" method="post">` to $row `<?php echo $row['id'];?>" method="post">` for it to recognize the row id in which I click the delete button on.

Comment: @AaronMyers Right, $id['id'] needs to be $row['id'], I didn't notice it a while ago. Now I am puzzled, I did see the Id is something like 45 and if($id>0) should be evaluated to true. Try add a else statement and see if you reach there?

Comment: Maybe, also double check if your mysql user has the rights to delete on your database?

Comment: I've updated your code above. I added an else statement like you said and have filled in the alert it's catching at. I will check the user permission on the mysql now.

Comment: @AaronMyers Just noticed in you previous comment "Okay, when I click delete for the record with id=45, I got a prompt said "Id to delete: 0" and when I click ok", you actually got a Id 0 alert, that means $_POST['id'] is not set properly by http post. After you changed your form from $id['id'] to $row['id'], do you still get the Invalid ID alert?

Comment: mysql user connection has permissions to delete

Comment: For some reason (even though 'id' is being set to 45) which I can see in the url from the from action, it is not being recognized as true when run through the php. It then proceeds to the else statement I have added. Any clues as to why that might be?

Comment: @Peter I get an "Id to delete: 0" on both instances. The difference is in the url. When the form action is set to $id, the url reads "/useraccounts.php?id=" and when the form action is set to $row, the url reads "/useraccounts.php?id=45" but in both scenerios the prompt says "Id to delete: 0"

Comment: Normally embedding parameters in the URL like "useraccounts.php?id=45" is passed as GET request. Your form is doing method="post", I am not sure if that will force the parameter be passed by POST. Two thing you can  try, first check if $_GET['id'] is set with your id value. Or add a hidden input with name set to id and value set to the row id.

Comment: Finally! That did it!! That was a struggle. Thanks so much for sticking through! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: :)  All good. Glad it worked at last.